# various class inject without using getBean() method

Tags: spring

I have 3 classes say for example: A, B and C. all these three classes are independent to each other. there is no parent child relationship.  In class c, if I want to use A and B without using getBean method how to inject and use it in class c?
Is there any other way to do it in spring latest version. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: Why not just using `@Resource` or `@Autowired` annotations to inject instances of `A` and `B`? Do you have a sample code that is not working, to get a better idea about ur question?

Comment: The are 3 ways in Spring to inject dependencies: 1) XML configuration, 2) Using the @Autowired (and other similar annotation) and 3) using Java Config. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use autowiring to inject A and B in C:

```
@Component
public class A {
    ...
}

@Component
public class B {
    ...
}

@Component
public class C {
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    ... use A and B ..
}
```